# Python - tkinter combobox save the value

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I'm trying to make a combobox with tkinter with an example as below

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

tkwindow = tk.Tk()

cbox = ttk.Combobox(tkwindow, values=['2.4', '5'], state='readonly')
cbox.grid(column=0, row=0)

tkwindow.mainloop()
```

I want when I select an option from combo box, let say I choose '2.4'. Then I can store that '2.4' in a variable and use later in my code.
I tried to search here, but all the case is just print a value. I don't want print, I want store a value.

Any ideas on this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can take those examples, see what is passed to `print`, save it to a variable and do whatever you want with it

Comment: According to this https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Combobox.get `cbox.get()` will give you the value you need. Should I make this an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried cbox.get() but it's not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you are trying to accomplish we can use the `bind()` method and the `get()` method.

I noticed in your code in the comment section (looks like its been deleted now) you tried to do `c = cbox.get()` however this value is not being updated because its only being called once on initialization of your program. Instead we can use `cbox.get()` directly in our `if` statements and then assign that value to the global variable `c`.

We need a function that can be called when the Selected event is fired during the selection of an item in the Combo Box. We can assign a function to be called when this event is fired with the `bind()` method.

I have taken the code you pasted in your comments and reformatted it into something functional.

Update:

I added a button to print the current stored value of `c` to so you can check the value after each time you select from the Combo box.

See below code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


tkwindow = tk.Tk()
c = ""

# This function will check the current value of cbox and then set
# that value to the global variable c.
def check_cbox(event):
    global c
    if cbox.get() == '2.4':
        c = cbox.get() # this will assign the variable c the value of cbox
    if cbox.get() == '5':
        c = cbox.get()

def print_c_current_value():
    print(c)

cbox = ttk.Combobox(tkwindow, values=['2.4', '5'], state='readonly')
cbox.grid(column=0, row=0)
# This bind calls the check_box() function when an item is selected.
cbox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", check_cbox)

tk.Button(tkwindow, text="Print C", command=print_c_current_value).grid(column=0, row=1)
tkwindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Got it Mike. Thank you very much.